# How can I adjust my autoloader so it will load my classes?

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

My project structure is the following:

```
.
└── src
    ├── Domain
    │   ├── Customer
    │   │   ├── Basic.php
    │   │   └── Premium.php
    │   ├── Book.php
    │   ├── Customer.php
    │   ├── Payer.php
    │   └── Person.php
    └── init.php
```

My script `init.php` contains the following:

```
<?php

use Bookstore\Domain\Book;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer;

function autoloader($classname) {
    $lastSlash = strpos($classname, '\\') + 1;
    $classname = substr($classname, $lastSlash);
    $directory = str_replace('\\', '/', $classname);
    $filename = __DIR__ . '/src/' . $directory . '.php';
    require_once($filename);
}

spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

$basic = new Basic(1, "name", "surname", "email");
$premium = new Premium(2, "name", "surname", "email");
var_dump($basic);
var_dump($premium);
```

And my error is:

> PHP Warning:  require_once(/srv/http/libro_php7/src/asic.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/http/libro_php7/init.php on line 11
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/srv/http/libro_php7/src/asic.php' (include_path='.:') in /srv/http/libro_php7/init.php on line 11

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Autoloader

First of all, you should probably adjust your autoloader to ignore classnames which are not within the `Bookstore` namespace, and just simplify it to:

```
function autoloader($classname) {
    /**
     * only handle classnames starting with "Bookstore\"
     */
    if (0 === strpos($className, 'Bookstore\\')) {
        $filename = __DIR__ . '/src/' . str_replace('\\', '/', $className) . '.php';

        require_once $filename;
    }
}
```

### Imports

Second, you are missing imports (that's why the autoloader cannot properly find your classes

- `Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Basic`
- `Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Premium` (doesn't event get this far, fails before you create an instance of it)

#### Adjust imports

```
<?php

use Bookstore\Domain\Book;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Basic;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer\Premium;

// see definition above
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

$basic = new Basic(1, "name", "surname", "email");
$premium = new Premium(2, "name", "surname", "email");
var_dump($basic);
var_dump($premium);
```

#### Reference classes relative to imports

```
<?php

use Bookstore\Domain\Book;
use Bookstore\Domain\Customer;

// see definition above
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

$basic = new Customer\Basic(1, "name", "surname", "email");
$premium = new Customer\Premium(2, "name", "surname", "email");
var_dump($basic);
var_dump($premium);
```